# From which Consulate should I apply for Schengen Visa?

Tags: visas, schengen

My itinerary is as described below:

22nd December - Land in Paris ( 9 am)

26th December - Leave from Paris in evening via Bus (5 Days)

27th December - Arrive at Zurich in Morning, Stay till 1st January 3.30pm ( 5.5 days)

1st Jan - Take a flight to Paris from Zurich in afternoon (3.30 pm).

1st Jan - Leave for India from Paris Airport.

Which Embassy should I apply Visa for?

Comment: The times are nearly equal. Do you have specific purpose to your visit in either Paris or Zurich? If so, that would be the main destination.

Comment: No just Tourism.

Comment: Might as well go with France - you start there.

Comment: Unless you do something special in Switzerland that would mark it as the main destination, you should apply to the first Schengen country you will enter, namely France.

Comment: @AliAwan was right. The criteria is based on more number of nights and not on days.

Answer (score 0):

According to schengen visa rules, you should apply where you would be staying maximum number of days. If you are spending equal number of days in schengen countries, then you will have to apply where you will be entering first.

In your case you are staying 4 nights (22 December to 25 December) in France and also France is your first port of entry, but also you are staying 5 nights Switzerland (27 December to 31st December). Therefore Switzerland is your main destination and you should apply to Switzerland. Schengen Embassies/Consulates or VFS counts Schengen stay by calculating according to booking. Since you are travelling on 26 at night that means 26 would not be counted. you will also have to provide bus tickets for 26 December with your itinerary.

These are all contact details for Switzerland Visa centers (India):

https://www.vfsglobal.ch/switzerland/india/contact_us.html

Comment: Why wouldn't the 26th be counted? It's about total time spent in the country, not nights spent in a hotel.

Comment: @JonathanReez because on 26 he will be travelling on a bus

Comment: His bus wouldn't leave France until the 27th, so he would be considered to have spent the 26th there.

Comment: @JonathanReez why the downvote, thats how schengen counts i have obtained more than 15 times schenegn visa

Comment: @JonathanReez on 26 leaving the bus in the evening

Comment: Could you provide a source for "if you leave by bus that day won't be counted"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48028/discussion-between-ali-awan-and-jonathanreez).

Comment: @JonathanReez please tell finally where to apply

Comment: @Shashank technically if we count your stay in days from 22-26(5 days in france), and from 27-1st jan(5.5 would also be count as 6 days), still i believe switzerland. Monday morning call both france and Swiss embassies and find out :)-

Comment: I ll be like in France for more few hours before I depart.

Comment: @Shashank If you are spending more time in france so basically , france is your main destination

Comment: i am not really sure about that. but definitely i am spending one night extra in swiss

Comment: @Shashank thats what i mean, maybe in india they count the other way, consulate general (Italy,germany) in Karachi counts according to hotel booking as per night for tourist visas

Comment: @Shashank you will have to call both embassies, they are closing your question here